# disabling specific signature scheme in TLS handshake using java

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, tls1.2, handshake

My java 8 application is communicating with other system via rest, secured with TLS1.2.
Last 2 java patches (261, 271) has broken the connection, because they have added some backward compatibility with TLS1.3. During the handshake, it started using some newer signature scheme - `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256` instead of, previously working`rsa_pkcs1_sha256` (named `SHA256withRSA` in java8u251), which is not working because it's trying to reach my private key (during `CertificateVerify` handhake step), which is protected by HSM, thus it's not available to read it.

I would like to disable this new signature scheme, because the older one is still sufficient and it worked on previous java patch and it's also used in a few other connections my application.

I have found this solution - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8227445 but when I set this setting by direct signature scheme name `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256`, it didn't work. Do you know what name should I pass there to disable this specific signature scheme (or all `rsa_pss_*` signature schemes group)?

Comment: Which http client are you using? Can you post an example of your client ssl configuration?

Comment: ```CloseableHttpClient```  with ```SSLConnectionSocketFactory``` (supported protocols - "TLSv1.2", supported cipher suites ```TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 ``` and a ```DefaultHostnameVerifier```

Comment: I was able to disable this scheme (not returning rsa_pss* algorithms in ClientHello anymore), but it still tries to use it, because while consuming CertificateRequest, the server side sends ```"supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256,...``` and it's trying to connect using those algorithms in the order the server has returned.

Comment: I would try to use `java.security` file, which will configure TLS for whole JVM. On JDK 8 and earlier, edit the `<java-home>/lib/security/java.security`. All Java TLS changes are in the roadmap - https://java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html. You can find in the release notes/additional information what was changed. I'm not sure if you can override default cipher order in the java somehow - it needs some debugging/testing.

Comment: I have modified java.security file but with no luck

Comment: The RSA PSS signature scheme differs from RSA PKCS1 only in the way the message is hashed and padded. Your HSM certainly knows how to encrypt a byte array with your private key, So maybe the solution would be to use a `SSLContext` (or other interface) implementation that supports RSA PSS?

Comment: @MarcinMikołajczyk did you ever get a solution to this problem, I too am hitting this issue now.

Comment: @Paul, I have reported this issue to Oracle team and they have fixed the jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms property in .291 patch. I have also got an update from nCipher software (hsm) to handle the RSA PSS algorithm without having to update java.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinMikołajczyk I appreciate the reply. I'll look into the .291 patch that could get me out of a hole in relation to this issue.